# Promise.all not waiting for promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to upload an array of files to an s3 bucket. I'm building an array of promises for each file, that generates the pre-signed URL, blobs the file and then does the upload. Each promise *should* resolve once the upload is complete.

When all the uploads are complete, I try to refresh the page.

I'm attempting to do this with the following code:

```
async function uploadFiles() {
  let requestArray = files.map(file => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      handleDocs.GenerateUrl(file.fileName, "{!OppName}", async (result, event) => {
        let preSignedUrl = result.Data.toString().replace(/amp;/gm, "");
        let blob = b64toBlob(file.fileString, result.ContentType);

        await fetch(preSignedUrl, {
          method: "PUT",
          body: blob,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": result.ContentType,
          },
        });

        resolve();
      });
    });
  });

  await Promise.all(requestArray);
  document.location.reload();
}
```

My guess is that the `handleDocs.GenerateUrl` is behaving in a way that I don't understand (it's a call to a backend Salesforce / APEX service that actually generates the pre-signed URL), and I'm wiring the promises up incorrectly.

I've not been able to find any examples that solve a similar problem and that have worked for me.

The actual logic seems fine since the files do upload successfully most of the time. Is there any issue with how I'm building up the promises?

Any help would be appreciated!

I realise there's already a question around this, but the underlying issue appears to be different.

Comment: Try Promise.all(requestArray).then(document.location.reload());

Comment: Sorry, how are you confirming that `await Promise.all(...)` isn't awaiting the promise resolution before reloading?

Comment: @Frazer why would you do that? There's already an `await` there

Comment: `Promise.all()` returns early if one of the requests fail, make sure that didn't happen. Add a try/catch around your `Promise.all()`

Comment: Side note: `let preSignedUrl = result.Data.toString().replace(/amp;/gm, "")` what is this? Shouldn't you be HTML decoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured out the cause and solution; I just misinterpreted what was going on with the promises.

This turned out to be caused by some of the other stuff on the page we were working on.

Part of the functionality we had was the ability to delete documents from S3, which is done with a call to an API we've written.

As part of our testing, we'd upload a file, delete it and then re-upload it, which is when we would see this issue.

As it turns out, `document.location.reload();` is resubmitting the delete data as part of the page reload. Changing this to `window.location.href = window.location.href;` fixed the problem we were having. Doesn't seem to be anything wrong with how the promises were being handled, so apologies for the misleading question.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what the actual issue is, but something that might make things easier to understand is promisifying the URL generation:

```
function generateUrlP(file) {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    handleDocs.GenerateUrl(
      file.fileName,
      "{!OppName}",
      (result, event) => resolve(result),
    ),
  );
}

async function uploadFiles() {
  const requestArray = files.map(async file => {
    const result = await generateUrlP(file);
    const preSignedUrl = result.Data.toString().replace(/amp;/gm, "");
    const blob = b64toBlob(file.fileString, result.ContentType);
    return fetch(preSignedUrl, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: blob,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": result.ContentType,
      },
    });
  });

  await Promise.all(requestArray);
  document.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why do you think this would behave differently? Seems to be the same logic, just switched around?

Comment: As I said in the preface for the answer, I'm not sure what the OP's actual problem is, but this might make it easier to read/understand/debug.

Comment: I realize you said that and I'm suggesting that without an explanation, it's just a guess and should not be an answer. I cannot see how this would behave differently, I'm asking you to explain how this could possibly behave differently

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is almost certainly generated by one single `promise` of the array failing.

Try this:

```
async function uploadFiles() {
  // an async function is a function that returns a promise
  let requestArray = files.map(async (file) => { 
    try {
      handleDocs.GenerateUrl(file.fileName, "{!OppName}", async (result, event) => {
        try {
          let preSignedUrl = result.Data.toString().replace(/amp;/gm, "");
          let blob = b64toBlob(file.fileString, result.ContentType);

          await fetch(preSignedUrl, {
            method: "PUT",
            body: blob,
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": result.ContentType,
            },
          });
        } catch(e){
          console.log(`Error in handleDocs`, e)
        }
      });

    } catch (e){
      console.log(`Error in requestArray`, e);
    }
  });
  await Promise.all(requestArray);
};


document.location.reload();
```

Comment: That'd cause the `await` before the reload to also throw. I don't think quietly skipping a file is a good option either.

Comment: I don't like answers that say "almost certainly", but it's the only thing I can think of. @Akx it's logging the error, it's not completely silent. But yeah, a try catch around the whole thing would be clearer

Comment: without being able to actually run the code and put everything in `try`/`catch` and figure out the issue, this is the closest thing to a solution possible. Also, I can't think of a way that the first `async` function can throw an error given everything is inside a try/catch block.